# Executing an if else shell command from perl

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I have never run into this scenario before so I could use a little help.  I am trying to issue an if/else statement from a shell command but within perl.  I've tried system and exec with no success.  Here's a sample of the code

```
if ($os eq 'Ubuntu'){
    system('if ! dpkg -l curl &> /dev/null; then apt-get install curl -y; fi');
    foreach my $mod (keys %deb){
        eval "use $mod";
        if($@){
            system("apt-get install $deb{$mod} -y");
            eval "use $mod";
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the command `if ! dpkg -l curl &> /dev/null; then apt-get install curl -y; fi` in shell it works fine but executing it from perl is skips the `if` part and goes right on to installing it.

Comment: You may need to explicitly invoke the shell instead of relying on Perl to figure out you want to do that, as in `system('/bin/sh -c if ! dpkg ...')`

Comment: invoking the system('/bin/sh -c if ! dpkg ...') gets me closer but it is complaining now !: 1: !: Syntax error: end of file unexpected.  Maybe I need to escape some characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if` works perfectly fine.

```
$ perl -e'system("if ! true ; then echo ok ; fi")'

$ perl -e'system("if ! false ; then echo ok ; fi")'
ok
```

There is a problem, though. What you posted is a `bash` command, but `system(EXPR)` is short for `system('/bin/sh', '-c', EXPR)`. Simply replacing

```
system(EXPR)
```

with

```
system('/bin/bash', '-c', EXPR)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid getting into the details of `if` syntax and also simplify it a bit by using `||` instead of negation. To try it out on the command line

```
perl -we 'system("rpm -q NO_PACK &> /dev/null || echo \"install package\"")'
```

I can only test on RHEL right now thus `rpm`. However, on RHEL I find this to work fine, too

```
perl -we 'system("if ! rpm -q NO >& /dev/null ; then echo install; fi")'
```

It is the syntax in the command that conflicts with the shell invoked by `system`, which is `dash` on Ubuntu (itself being a link to `sh`). Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) and [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176646/thissuitisblacknot) for comments on this.  In particular, the redirection `&>` does not work since that is specifically `bash`'s feature. Then you can change to the generic `> /dev/null 2>&1` which sends `STDOUT` stream to `/dev/null` and redirects `STDERR` stream (2) to the same place where `STDOUT` (1) goes

```
system('dpkg -l curl > /dev/null 2>&1 || apt-get install curl -y');
```

On a RHEL system the `sh` is a link to `bash`, thus `&>` works.  Note that the `2&>1` redirection works as well. However, in my opinion a better solution is to specify which shell you want to use.

The [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) allows one to *not* invoke the shell, by supplying arguments in a list. Then the program given as the first argument is run directly, without triggering the shell, with the rest of the list being passed to it. This is the way to get the right shell to run your command, as you can specify that shell as the first argument in the list. This is shown in the answer by [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami).

Comment: thank you, I will give that a try for future implementations

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for the comment -- this was perplexing.  I tried with what should be a clear `if` statement but it was using `!` for expansion.  I tried `[...]`, and I couldn't get the `test` to work either. This, on the other hand, works from the terminal from `bash` and as the above one-liner. Also, I am not sure why it is not valid -- I think that `rpm` exits with 1/0, and so should `dpkg`.  Can they not be used as conditionals and execute as a side effect?

Comment: The `&>` is a bash-ism, so I think that is the problem, not the `!`. `!` is valid syntax according to the dash manpage (dash is the default shell on Debian), although I haven't tested yet.

Comment: (`dash` is a POSIX-compliant `sh`. In other words, `dash` *is* `sh`)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Thank you, adjusted.  So Debian uses `sh` -- which doesn't take `&>`? That was a surprise to me altogether.  (On RHEL here `sh` is a link to `bash` so I guess that's why my tests work.) Either way, [ikegami](http://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)'s answer of course bypasses these details.

Comment: Yep. On Debian and Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash`. `&>` is specific to bash, and only relatively new versions of bash at that; it wasn't added until v4.0 (released in 2009).

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed a little problematic so I went about another way to solve it.  Here is what I ended up doing which gives me the same end result

```
if ($os eq 'Ubuntu'){
    my $check = `dpkg --get-selections | grep "^curl *" | awk '{print \$1}'`;
    if(!$check){ system('apt-get install curl -y > /dev/null'); }
        foreach my $mod (keys %deb){
            eval "use $mod";
            if($@){
            system("apt-get install $deb{$mod} -y");
            eval "use $mod";
        }
    }
}
```